# How to destructuring with default value in ecmascript 6

Tags: ecmascript-6, default-parameters, destructuring

How can I do destructing with default parameter?

```
foo function({data, someOptional = 'default'}){
}
```

How can I use those features of ES6?

Comment: `{data, someOptional = 'default'}` shoukl work fine. What's wrong with it?

Comment: someOptional always get 'default'

Comment: That's the way to do it. If it doesn't work, the environment the code runs in  may not implement destructuring correctly.

Comment: I'm using webpack (1.12.2) and babel (5.6.4)

Comment: 5.6.4 is quite old. Try a newer version instead. You [can see here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20func(%7Bdata%2C%20someOptional%20%3D%20'default'%7D)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(someOptional)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunc(%7BsomeOptional%3A%2042%7D)&playground=true) that works just fine.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Btw, `func function` seems to be a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi I edited it to foo. the calling will be `foo({data:[123]})` or `foo({filterBy:'else'})`

Comment: @snoof: It still should be `function foo(…)`, not `foo function(…)`. And yes, if you don't pass `someOptional`, then it is expected that you get `'default'`? What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that the calls could be either:

- `foo({data:[123]})`
- `foo({filterBy:'else'})`

In the second one, you're not passing `data` which is not optional in the way you declared you're function.

If `data` is also optional, you should declare your function this way (specifying `data`'s default value):

```
function foo({data=[], someOptional='default'}){}
```

That way, you'll be able to make the calls you mentioned.

Though, if you don't wan't to pass **any argument** at all and rely on the default parameters, you should declare it that way:

```
function foo({data=[], someOptional='default'} = {}){}
```

That way you'll even be able to make this kind of call : `foo()`